# Circular dependency in a pattern for system with many dependent components

Tags: python, design-patterns, circular-dependency

The following pattern is needed:

1. Computer has physical components (hard drive, screen, speaker)
2. You can install apps on it (that's everything computer knows about apps)
3. Apps cannot function without a computer, they have to be installed
4. Apps can use physical components of the computer

Since computer contains apps and apps need to access the computer there is a circular dependency. Is it an appropriate case for using it or is there a better pattern for such problem?

Example code:

```
class Screen:

    def display(self, image):
        print('Displaying "{}"'.format(image))


class Speaker:

    def play(self, sound):
        print('Playing "{}"'.format(sound))


class HardDrive:

    def write(self, data):
        print('Writing "{}" to disk'.format(data))


class Applications(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, name, app):
        try:
            self.__getitem__(name)
            raise PermissionError('App "{name}" is already installed!'.format(name=name))
        except KeyError:
            super(Applications, self).__setitem__(name, app)


class Computer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.speaker = Speaker()
        self.disk = HardDrive()
        self.apps = Applications()

    def install_app(self, factory, *args, **kwargs):
        app = factory(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.apps[app.name] = app

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return self.apps[item]
        except KeyError:
            pass


class App(object):

    def __init__(self, computer, name=None):
        self.computer = computer
        self.name = name


class PdfReader(App):

    def __init__(self, computer, name='pdf_reader'):
        super(PdfReader, self).__init__(computer, name)
        self.computer.disk.write('pdf reader data')

    def read_document(self, document):
        self.computer.screen.display(document)


class VideoPlayer(App):

    def __init__(self, computer, name='video_player'):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(computer, name)
        self.computer.disk.write('pdf reader data')

    def play_video(self, video):
        self.computer.screen.display(video)
        self.computer.speaker.play(video)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    home_pc = Computer()
    home_pc.install_app(PdfReader)
    home_pc.install_app(VideoPlayer)
    home_pc.pdf_reader.read_document('Harry_Potter.pdf')
    home_pc.video_player.play_video('Pulp_Fiction.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why circular? Why the (missing) `installer`?

```
class Computer:

   # no change: def __init__(self):

   def install_app(self, installer, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
           app = installer(self, *args, **kwargs)               # def installer() missing
           self.apps[app.name] = app  # install if it worked    # but I assume it does smth
       except InstallError ex:
           # do something if installer throws InstallError
           pass
```

Raise a InstallError if the installation process did not work. If it works, simply add the app to the computer. No circularity involved.

btw. I have about 2-4 video-player-software on my laptop (Real Player, vlc, ...) - youe get more flexible if you allow to give the "name" of the app when instanciating it to allow for more then one VideoPlayer-App.

Comment: 1. Circular because apps have `computer` attribute. And computers contain apps.  

2. In this case `installer` is  class object. So `installer()` is calling `__init__`. Maybe this name is a bit misleading, renamed to `factory`.  

3. VideoPlayer is supposed to be a concrete application. VLCPlayer would then be a subclass. But technically it should be possible to install multiple instances of the same app, so it makes sense to make `name` an instance variable.